# populate multipe selectboxes from same table

Tags: php, html-select

I would like to populate three selectboxes with the same items (from one database table). 
This is the code I have so far. I want to avoid three queries. Would you help me with a solution to populate multiple selectboxes?

```
<select name="resort_3" class="swcomp" data-index="3">
<?php   
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$sQuery2 = "SELECT DISTINCT res_id, resort from sv_snow WHERE lud='$today' ORDER by resort";
$sResult2 = mysql_query($sQuery2) or die('Error, query 2 failed');

while($ro = mysql_fetch_assoc($sResult2))
{
 echo '<option value="'. $ro['res_id'] . '">'. ucfirst($ro['resort']) . '</option> '; 
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Just add three options to one loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the options in a string and then assign those to all 3 select boxes. Simple as that

```
<?php
while($ro = mysql_fetch_assoc($sResult2))
{
 $options.='<option value="'. $ro['res_id'] . '">'. ucfirst($ro['resort']) . '</option> '; 
}
?>


<select name="resort_1" class="swcomp" data-index="1">
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>

<select name="resort_2" class="swcomp" data-index="2">
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>

<select name="resort_3" class="swcomp" data-index="3">
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```